# Сложный sql запрос и группировка

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT vr.id as id,ut.name as unit, vr.count AS count, c.articles as articles, c.url as url, c.rating as rating, t.text as text, t.minitext as minitext, t.name as name, c.status_id as status, i.img as img, i.water as water, vr.cost as cost
FROM product c 
 RIGHT JOIN productVariants vr ON vr.product_id = c.id 
 LEFT JOIN product_text t ON c.id = t.product_id  
 LEFT JOIN productImgs i ON vr.id = i.productVariant_id 
 LEFT JOIN productCategory pc ON pc.product_id = c.id 
 LEFT JOIN units_text ut ON c.unit_id = ut.unit_id 
WHERE t.lang_id = ? AND pc.category_id = ? AND t.lang_id = ut.lang_id 
 AND i.number = 1 
    AND vr.main = 1  
ORDER BY vr.cost ASC
LIMIT ?,?
```

`

Вместо ? значения переменных.

Задача, Выбирать только с одним из productVariants чтобы не использовать поле vr.main

~ то что хотелось бы получить, но увы так не работает

```
SELECT vr.id as id,ut.name as unit, vr.count AS count, c.articles as articles, c.url as url, c.rating as rating, t.text as text, t.minitext as minitext,t.name as name,c.status_id as status, i.img as img, i.water as water, vr.cost as cost 
FROM product c 
 RIGHT JOIN productVariants vr ON vr.product_id = c.id 
 LEFT JOIN product_text t ON c.id = t.product_id  
 LEFT JOIN productImgs i ON vr.id = i.productVariant_id 
 LEFT JOIN productCategory pc ON pc.product_id = c.id 
 LEFT JOIN units_text ut ON c.unit_id = ut.unit_id 
WHERE t.lang_id = ? AND pc.category_id = ? AND t.lang_id = ut.lang_id 
 AND i.number = 1 
 AND vr.main = 1  
GROUP BY vr.product_id
ORDER BY vr.cost ASC
LIMIT ?,?
```

Логически правильный порядок связей.

```
    SELECT vr.id as id,ut.name as unit, vr.count AS `count`, c.articles as articles, c.url as url, c.rating as rating, t.text as text, t.minitext as minitext,t.name as name, c.status_id as status, i.img as img, i.water as water, vr.cost as cost 
FROM `productVariants` vr 
INNER JOIN `product` c ON vr.product_id = c.id 
INNER JOIN product_text t ON c.id = t.product_id 
LEFT JOIN productImgs i ON vr.id = i.productVariant_id 
INNER JOIN productCategory pc ON pc.product_id = c.id 
INNER JOIN units_text ut ON c.unit_id = ut.unit_id 
WHERE t.lang_id = ? AND pc.category_id = ? AND t.lang_id = ut.lang_id AND i.number = 1 AND vr.main = 1 
ORDER BY vr.cost ASC
LIMIT ?,?
```

**Пришёл к**

```
SELECT vr.id as id,ut.name as unit, vr.count AS `count`, c.articles as articles, c.url as url, c.rating as rating, t.text as text, t.minitext as minitext,t.name as name, c.status_id as status, i.img as img, i.water as water, vr.cost as cost 
FROM `productVariants` vr
INNER JOIN `product` c ON vr.product_id = c.id 
INNER JOIN product_text t ON c.id = t.product_id 
INNER JOIN productImgs i ON vr.id = i.productVariant_id 
INNER JOIN productCategory pc ON pc.product_id = c.id 
INNER JOIN units_text ut ON c.unit_id = ut.unit_id 
WHERE t.lang_id = ? AND pc.category_id = ? AND t.lang_id = ut.lang_id AND i.number = 1 AND vr.id = (SELECT id FROM productVariants invr WHERE invr.product_id = c.id LIMIT 0,1) 
ORDER BY vr.cost 
LIMIT ?,?
```

Но понимаю что ситуация требует мнения сбоку.

Comment: приведите код в читаемый вид. для выделения кода используйте кнопку с фигурными скобками `{}` на панели инструментов редактора поля для вопроса.

Comment: Несколько минут искал разницу между двумя приведенными запросами - ее нету! Уберите тогда лишний запрос.

Comment: *Задача, Выбирать только с одним из productVariants чтобы не использовать поле vr.main* Это не задача, а выбранный способ её решить. Формулируйте именно задачу. Кстати, у Вас бОльшая часть LEFT JOIN вырождена в INNER. И совершенно непонятно, почему выбран именно такой порядок связывания таблиц - ведь сервер их будет сканировать именно в указанном порядке.

Comment: Что значит "_так не работает_". Возвращает ошибку (если да, то какую), дает не верные данные (если да, то чем они отличаются от верных) ?  И по запросу не видно что такое "_один productVariants_", вижу условие на vr.main=1 - а это уникальный ключ в variants ?

Comment: Akina, приведу в порядок последовательность связывания таблиц. Да, это быстрый вариант постепенно родившийся в процессе.

Comment: Сейчас подготовлю ожидание и реальность

Comment: @DaemonHK, так вот и написал бы в ответе запрос, от которого не ляжет.

Comment: @DaemonHK, для тестирования заполнил таблицы: 10 млн строк в продуктах. Но потом уменьшил остальные до 100 тысяч строк(а именно текст продуктов и вариантов, чтобы было достаточно)

Comment: http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1509755569/daa7c426/19271445.jpg Это при том что размер данных этих таблиц ~ 30 мб. По прежнему остаюсь при мнении, что если есть возможность использовать меньшее количество запросов к базе, то нужно это делать.

Comment: Провёл расследование. Действительно, при 200к в каждый таблице имеем проблему. 15 секунд запрос. Это очень много. Происходит при первом запросе с заданными параметрами к базе данных, после чего запрос подготавливается и имеем быстрый ответ. Нужно найти золотую средину.

Comment: Стоит убрать изображение и единицы измерения. Остальные данные - жизненно необходимы для отбора только нужных строк. при 10к товаров имеем 1 секунду загрузки. Костыль с вариантами товара придуман для 1с(ненавижу). Поэтому в условиях без него всё будет ещё лучше.

Comment: @Qwertiy ого, у нас тут комментарии удаляют даже, ну ок...

Comment: @webservice я бы на Вашем месте пожалел все таки БД и выполнял несколько последовательных запросов с необходимой обработкой. И да, как говорил Akina, сформулируйте задачу

Comment: @DaemonHK, комментарий удялил не я. Тем не менее, желательно писать комментарии более осмотрительно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я и не говорил, что Вы, просто из администрации кто-то, ничего против не имею

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT vr.id as id,ut.name as unit, vr.count AS `count`, c.articles as articles, c.url as url, c.rating as rating, t.text as text, t.minitext as minitext,t.name as name, c.status_id as status, i.img as img, i.water as water, vr.cost as cost 
FROM `productVariants` vr
INNER JOIN `product` c ON vr.product_id = c.id 
INNER JOIN product_text t ON c.id = t.product_id 
INNER JOIN productImgs i ON vr.id = i.productVariant_id 
INNER JOIN productCategory pc ON pc.product_id = c.id 
INNER JOIN units_text ut ON c.unit_id = ut.unit_id 
WHERE t.lang_id = ? AND pc.category_id = ? AND t.lang_id = ut.lang_id AND i.number = 1 AND vr.id = (SELECT id FROM productVariants invr WHERE invr.product_id = c.id LIMIT 0,1) 
ORDER BY vr.cost 
LIMIT ?,?
```

Спасибо тем кто комментировал. Учту то что стоит снизить нагрузку на бд.